# implement a dynamic alert popup in ionic 2 list item, and set selected value in item

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

in my ionic 2 application, i have a list with dynamic items. In each item, i have button item. On clicking particular button item, a dynamic alert popup will come. Once i select an option from popup, that value will be set as item content. But in my case, when i select a value from popup, it appears in all items. i want to set it to the only selected or clicked item. please help me out to solve this issue.

**HTML Code**

```
    <ion-item *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">

        <ion-card-content class="no-left-right-padding card_class">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-6>
                <ion-icon name="card" end (click)="removeItemFromCart(item)"></ion-icon>
                <span margin-left class="service-item">{{item.cost}} BD</span>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6>
                <ion-icon name="clock" end (click)="removeItemFromCart(item)"></ion-icon>
                <span margin-left class="service-price">{{item.time | number: '1.0-0'}} Mins</span>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        </ion-card-content>

    <ion-item button class="employee_item" margin-left no-lines (click)="select_emplyee(i)"> {{employee_data||'Select Employee'}}</ion-item>

    </ion-item>
```

**.ts code**

select_emplyee(index){

```
console.log(index);

              let loader1 = this.loadingController.create({
                 spinner: 'dots',
                 content: 'Please wait...',
               });            

              loader1.present().then(() => {
              this.httpservice.load_single_saloons_employe(this.navParams.get('provider_id')).subscribe(
              data => {
                console.log(data); 
                this.Employee_alert = this.atrCtrl.create({});

                this.full_employees=data;

                console.log(this.full_employees);

                  this.Employee_alert.setTitle('Select employee..');

                          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                          this.emp=data[i];
                          this.Employee_alert.addInput({
                                        type:'radio',
                                        label: this.emp.member_name,
                                        value: this.emp.id
                                        })
                          }

                           this.Employee_alert.addButton({
                             text: 'Done',
                             cssClass:'alertCustomCss',
                             handler: (data) => {
                               if(data){
                                 console.log(data);
                                 this.employee_data=this.emp.member_name;
                                 // d.textContent = this.employee_data;
                               }                                            
                             }
                           });
                           this.Employee_alert.setCssClass('alertCustomCss');
                           this.Employee_alert.present();

              loader1.dismiss();  

              },
               err => {
               console.log(err);
               loader1.dismiss();
              },
              () => console.log('Movie Search Complete')
              );


               });


 }
```

Comment: Can you post some more html code?

Comment: Hi Aniket, Which part of html code you need?. In this code, i provided the problem facing part. In the provided html code,   <ion-item button class="employee_item" margin-left no-lines (click)="select_emplyee(i)"> {{employee_data||'Select Employee'}}</ion-item>, this part iam facing issue.